# JAXB Moxy getValueByXpath gives null

Tags: xpath, jaxb, moxy

I want to see if a theme element exists with specified name in the following xml file.

**input.xml**

```
<data>
    <artifacts>
        <document id="efqw4eads">
            <name>composite</name>
        </document>
        <theme id="1">
            <name>Terrace</name>
        </theme>
        <theme id="2">
            <name>Garage</name>
        </theme>
        <theme id="3">
            <name>Reception</name>
        </theme>
        <theme id="4">
            <name>Grade II</name>
        </theme>
    </artifacts>
</data>
```

I have the following code. return true statement of the method is never executed. `answer` always contains a null value.

```
public boolean themeExists(String name, Data data){
    String expression = "artifacts/theme[name='"+name+"']/name/text()";
    String answer = jaxbContext.getValueByXPath(data, expression, null, String.class);
    if(answer == null || answer.equals("")){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your XML was broken, the closing `</data>` missed the `/`. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case isn't currently supported by [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  I have opened the following enhancement you can use to track our progress:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/413823

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll use JXPathContext for now.

Comment: Jeez.  As of 2.6.4, this still looks like not addressed?  Is Moxy a dead product?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<artifacts/>` element you're look for in the first axis step. Your XPath expression should be something like

```
String expression = "data/theme[name='"+name+"']/name/text()";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added <artifacts> element. It was there in the original code but the xpath still doesn't work.